# 7Zip command line - Help archiving files with abnormal extension

Tags: batch-file, command-line, 7zip, php-ziparchive

I have a legacy system that was developed years ago which receives and processes xml files. After processing the file the filename is changed from .xml to ."done" including the quotation marks. I need to write a batch file that will archive these ."done" files on a regular basis but don't seem to be able to get it to work using;

```
7z a archivename.zip *."done"
```

which creates the archive file but it is empty. I've tried specifying the files to archive with a few different variations without success.

Comment: quotes aren't valid in file names. How are these ."done" files created specifically?

Comment: I beleive the files are renamed by a service that processes the files. Unfortunatly there is no documentation what so ever.

Comment: Got it finally. Used; "7z archivename.zip *done*"

Comment: Sorry, this editor is not allowing me to add a return or asterisks. The answer was to use asterisk done asterisk. No dots, quotes, etc... Works for DOS dir command as well. Now i just have to wait while it compresses half a million files that have accumulated.

Comment: You can use a code block by surrounding your text in backticks. `*done*`

Comment: What operating system are you using?  `Double Quotes` are illegal characters in MSDOS and Windows filesystems.